# Key in dict.keys(), but dict.get(key) returns None

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries i.e. `dict[key1][key2]` should return a number. 
If I do `key2 in dict[key1]` this returns `True`, but `dict[key1].get(key2)` returns `None`.

I guess there is something quite fundamental I'm missing here, but I'm stuck.

As key1 is a `string`, and key2 is a `numpy.datetime64`.

edit:

```
key type: <type 'numpy.datetime64'>
key: 2014-08-11T02:00:00.000000+0200
Dict: {numpy.datetime64('2014-08-11T02:00:00.000000000+0200'): 1}
key in dict.keys() True
dict.items(): [(numpy.datetime64('2014-08-11T02:00:00.000000000+0200'), 1)]
dict.get(key): None
```

edit 2:

replaced by edit 3

Edit 3 (replacing edit 2):

Code:

```
vessel = df['Vessel'].iloc[0]
print "vessel:",vessel
ati = np.datetime64(df['ATI'].iloc[0])
print "ati type:",type(ati),"value:",ati
print "Self.sailing[vessel]:",self.sailing[vessel]
print "key in dict.keys():",ati in self.sailing[vessel].keys()
sailing = self.sailing[vessel].get(ati)
print "sailing:", sailing
print "dict[key]:",self.sailing[vessel][ati]
```

Output:

```
vessel: VESSEL2
ati type: <type 'numpy.datetime64'> value: 2014-07-21T02:00:00.000000+0200
Self.sailing[vessel]: {numpy.datetime64('2014-07-21T02:00:00.000000000+0200'): 1}
key in dict.keys(): True
sailing: None
dict[key]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/python/bmw_vpc/src/vpc_data_extractor.py", line 9, in <module>
    data.create_master_file()
  File "C:\dev\python\bmw_vpc\src\process.py", line 112, in create_master_file
    print "dict[key]:",self.sailing[vessel][ati]
KeyError: numpy.datetime64('2014-07-21T02:00:00.000000+0200')
```

edit 4:

code:

```
for key in self.sailing[vessel].keys():
    print "Vessel:",vessel,"ati:",ati,"ati == key:",ati == key
sailing = self.sailing[vessel].get(ati)
print "Vessel:",vessel,"sailing:", sailing
```

output:

```
Vessel: VESSEL2 ati: 2014-07-21T02:00:00.000000+0200 ati == key: True
Vessel: VESSEL2 sailing: None
```

edit 5:

Thanks to @jamylak's answer I made a workaround using the Timestamp instead of the the datetime64-object.

Comment: Could the value of `key2` be be `None`? `get()` returns the value at the specified key so is it possible that you dict looks like `{key1: {key2: None}`?

Comment: You will get `KeyError` if the second key is missing instead of none.

Comment: No, that's what's so strange. The value should never be None, and it is not None in the dicts where I see this error.

Comment: Could you do a `print dict` to verify that it is not None?

Comment: @anselm: I don't understand what you mean? I believe that dict.get(key) will return None if key is missing, but dict[key] will return KeyError

Comment: @anselm: as stated above, it's not None. and key in dict returns True

Comment: @rakke ah your right. Totally forgot about the `default=None`. What I mean is to print your actual dict and verify that you have a value. One thing I suspect might be a key/object comparison issue. Try to force key2 to a string and see if the problem still occur.

Comment: Can add the relevant parts of your dictionary to your question?

Comment: see edit above for an example

Comment: @rakke Please edit that into your question.

Comment: @IanAuld example added. Any more information you need?

Comment: @rakke I have tried without success to replicate your issue. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: It's not clear what's causing your problem - please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @IanAuld: actual code posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only option from the information you have given is that `key2` exists in `dict[key1]` and `key2` has a value of `None`

EDIT:

They are 2 completely different objects that just happen to look like the exact same object.

From your code there is:

```
numpy.datetime64('2014-07-21T02:00:00.000000+0200')
```

and

```
numpy.datetime64('2014-07-21T02:00:00.000000000+0200')
```

---

```
>>> (hash(numpy.datetime64('2014-07-21T02:00:00.000000000+0200'))
  == hash(numpy.datetime64('2014-07-21T02:00:00.000000+0200')))
False
```

The reason this is, is because when you check `in dict.keys()` it does an equality check (`==`) on each element in a `list` that is built by the `.keys()` method  and

```
numpy.datetime64('2014-07-21T02:00:00.000000000+0200') == numpy.datetime64('2014-07-21T02:00:00.000000+0200')
```

If you try running `key in dict`, it will return `False` because that doesnt build the intermediary `list` and instead uses `hash`

They are different objects to the dictionary because the `hash` is what the dictionary uses which is why `in dict.keys()` does not work.

`.get` also **does not** find it because it returns `None`, you can change the default `None` to something else to prove this.

---

As for the reason why they compare equal and have a different `hash`, I think some sort of bug.

Comment: @rakke I don't get your edit, why can't you show the actual log of commands you ran

Comment: @rakke You never ran `ati in self.sailing[vessel]` so theres absolutely no proof of that, which you said was true in the question

Comment: Yes I did in the first edit. I'm not making up output when posting, but I'll add id in the second edit as well....

Comment: @rakke Is all that code in edit 3 being executed at once or is anything happening in between?

Comment: if is all being executed at once, nothing in between. One exception: In order to reduce output I only did print "dict[key]:",self.sailing[vessel][ati] for one vessel so it is executed after: if vessel == "VESSEL2":

Comment: See your answer but still don't understand why key in dict.keys() return true? In addition: don't understand your comment about vessel? It's not there is only one VESSEL2, and ati is for VESSEL2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79446/discussion-between-rakke-and-jamylak).

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the following section of code with no issue. Can you follow through and see if you still get the same issue?

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> k = numpy.datetime64("2014-08-11T02:00:00.000000000+0200")
>>> print k
2014-08-11T08:00:00.000000000+0800
>>> dic = {"k":{k:1}}
>>> print dic
{'k': {numpy.datetime64('2014-08-11T08:00:00.000000000+0800'): 1}}
>>> dic.items()
[('k', {numpy.datetime64('2014-08-11T08:00:00.000000000+0800'): 1})]
>>> dic["k"].items()
[(numpy.datetime64('2014-08-11T08:00:00.000000000+0800'), 1)]
>>> dic["k"].get(k)
1
>>>
```

Comment: I get the same output as you for this. I'm on Python 2.7.9 (Python(x,y)) on windows

Comment: Same for me, I have tried to replicate OP's issue but I can't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use get twice:

```
dictionary.get('key1', {}).get('key2')
```

This will return None if key1 or key2 does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

A valid example of what probably happen in your script:

```
>>> dict = {'key1': {'key2': None}}
>>> print('key2' in dict['key1'])
True
>>> print(dict['key1']['key2'])
None
```

Comment: No, I agree that this could have been the case, but I also get a KeyError not None if I do dict[key1][key2]